# Post/Get Methode with href and list-group-iteam

Tags: laravel, post, get

I try to build a post/get method with an list group team / href. Here is my code...

```
@if(count($variableController) > 0)
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($variableController as $variableView)
                <a href='spielerAuswahl' class="list-group-item">{{$variableView->heimmannschaft}}</a>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
@endif
```

spielerAuswahl is my view. And after a click on the list-group-item I get to this view. But there I need the information from the list-group-item.

```
Route::post('/spielerAuswahl', function () {
    return 123;
    //var_dump($_POST)
});
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replcae post with get method like this:

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl', function () {
    return 123;
    //var_dump($_POST)
});
```

if you want to return spielerAuswahl as view

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl', function () {
    return view('spielerAuswahl');
});
```

dont forget 
`spielerAuswahl.blade.php` should be in `reousrces/view` directory

on the other hand if you want to send some data to view

change route to :

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl/{somevar}', function ($somevar) {
    return view('spielerAuswahl',compact('somevar'));
});
```

and send data like this:

```
@if(count($variableController) > 0)
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($variableController as $variableView)
                <a href='spielerAuswahl/{{ $variableView->id }}' class="list-group-item">{{$variableView->heimmannschaft}}</a>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
@endif
```

it was get method

if you want to use post method your action method should be POST

one way is using `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: view spielerAuswahl not found. but it is in resources/views. I take the get example... sorry I made an mistake

Comment: @HansMuff are you sure about spelling? dont forget case senstive ```spielerAuswahl``` is not ```spielerauswahl```

Comment: I have 2 fields (field1: 1 field2: 3) when I click on field1 I get back 1 but when I click on field2 I get back 2?! I think this is the id number? But I need the correct value inside...

Comment: ```{{ $variableView->id }}``` return id number you can relace it with any field that you want ```{{ $variableView->yourfield}}```